# SQL Conditioning - Importing Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need some help applying so condition to my sql script.

I Have a a .txt file with data - each line representing a row of Data.

Now I want to import this data based off of specific criteria.

See text file below

[image]

see imported into the table

[image]

I am managed to import it with criteria based off of Date field = not null however im struggling with the other criterea.

See criteria below (S , I , D , DS , O , L , F - These refer to product codes)

```
-- S , I , O , DS - IF QUANTITY IS = 0 THEN DONT IMPORT
-- S , I , 0 - IF DATE FIELD IS = NULL THEN STILL IMPORT
-- L , F - DONT IMPORT IF DATE FIELD IS = NULL
-- IF L , F BOTH HAVE A FILLED IN DATE FIELD , THEN DONT IMPORT
```

This is what i have tried

```
SELECT IDENTITY( INT, 1, 1) AS IDNUM, CAST( NULL AS VARCHAR(12) ) DEAL_ID, PHASE_NO, PHASE_DESC,ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER,DELIVERY_DATE,COST_PRICE,LIST_PRICE,QUANTITY,REF_NUM, CAST( NULL AS VARCHAR(12)) AS PROJECT_ID  
INTO #TMP_DEALS 
FROM DsetImport WHERE DELIVERY_DATE IS NOT NULL AND ISDATE (convert(datetime, DELIVERY_DATE , 103)) = 1 AND 
 COALESCE (CAST(CAST(REPLACE (QUANTITY,':', '.') AS DECIMAL(20,0)) AS INT), 0) > -1
 AND ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER IN ('I','D','DS','S','O')
```

Comment: You have tagged the question "oracle" but your syntax is SQL Server.  Please explain.

Comment: @gordonLinoff Apologies it was a wrong entry

Comment: Your requirements are ambigous, you have three that are "don't import" and one that is "still import", what if a row satisfies both a "don't import" and a "still import" condition?   You should re-write the "still import" condition into the form of a "don't import".

Comment: Also, your Quantity criteria says `= 0, don't import`, but in your query you say `> -1 to import`. `0 > -1`